Unable to use one line statement to get a value from a dictionary in a list, and then save it as a variable Python
I am pretty confused.
I have a list of dictionaries, like so:
options = [
    {'name':'Notifications','id':'1', 'url':'notifications'},
    {'name':'the directory','id':'2', 'url':'directory'},
    {'name':'the DBM Studios catalogue','id':'842', 'url':'dbm'},
    ]

I also have an id variable:
id = "842"

If I execute the following:
for option in options:
    if id == option['id']:
        print (f"url is {option['url']}")

I get the value of the url key as a string:
>>> url is dbm

If I execute it in 1 line, like so:
print ([option['url'] for option in options if id == option['id']])

I get it as a list:
>>> ['dbm']

Well, seems like the square brackets make it into a list. What if I replace it with round brackets?
print ((option['url'] for option in options if id == option['id']))

But that gives me an object, not a value:
>>> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7af8b523e7a0>

Turns out I can print the value like this:
print (*(option['url'] for option in options if id == option['id']))

Which returns:
>>> dbm

But if I try to save it as a variable and then print the variable:
url = *(option['url'] for option in options if id == option['id'])
print (url)

I get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/bin/pythonanywhere_runner.py", line 26, in _pa_run
    code = compile(f.read(), filename.encode("utf8"), "exec")
  File "/file.py", line 9
    url = *(option['url'] for option in options if id == option['id'])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here

I am looking more to understand what is going on than for a way to save it as a variable, as I can technically do this across multiple lines - but a solution as to how to do it would be great, too.

In the call to print() you're using * to spread all the results into separate function arguments. There's nothing equivalent when assigning to a variable.

Try url = tuple(option['url'] for option in options if id == option['id']))

You could also do: (url,) = [option['url'] for option in options if id == option['id']]; print(url)

Replace print (f"url is {option['url']}") in your for loop with my_result_list.append(option['url']) and then you'll have an equivalent construction to your single line List Comprehension. If you know you're always getting exactly one match, then just access index zero of the final result. Seems like an unnecessary hoop to jump through, though, as list comprehension is an efficient way to build lists, not just access single items... https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Your fundamental misunderstanding you have is that these constructs, list comprehensions, generator expressions, exist to make "one line statements". No! The purpose of these constructs is to create lists or generators using mapping/filtering operations . (side note, every value is an object in python). You need to understand these on their own terms and stop worrying about the number of lines. Lastly, using the * syntax is for iterable unpacking. Both lists and generators are iterables, so you could have done that with a list comprehension as well.

So, first you should learn about list comprehensions and relaed constructs. The accepted answer to this question is really good. Note, that will include the explanation for a generator expression, but you should Then you should probably learn what a generator is. You can learn about the * syntax in the linked duplicates above
